# SASS watch N folders without define them

Tags: css, sass, debian, precompile

I have a server with a folder structure like:

```
/var/www/aaa.com/
/var/www/bbb.com/
/var/www/ccc.com/
```

and with sass files, like:

```
/var/www/aaa.com/aaa.scss
/var/www/bbb.com/something/bbb.scss
/var/www/ccc.com/something/else/ccc.scss
```

Can i use only one watch command, to compile all the .scss files to the scss' directory? To compile to the same folder is perfect for me. Like this:

```
sass --watch /var/www/^(.*)$:/var/www/$1
```

And the result:

```
/var/www/aaa.com/aaa.scss -> /var/www/aaa.com/aaa.css
```

So I do not care about the structures or anything I just want the watch keep listening to EVERY scss files in the big structure, and if something changes, simply compile to the same folder. That's all.

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just watch the scss root folder:

```
sass --watch /var/www/:/var/www/
```